# Calling Another Component and Displaying its html Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Currently I am working with components so the problem I am facing is I have Index component and through Index component I want to display Search component and its template, lets get little deeper,
this is index.html 
[image: Index Page]

**index.component.ts**

```
 export class LandingPageComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    searchData:Object=[];


    onIndustryChange(event:string) {
        this.searchData[1]=event;
    }

    onlocationChange(event:string) {

        this.searchData[0]=event;


    }

    searchJobs(){
        //navigate to find compnennt and call the search method in find component
 based on the **searchData** of this component i.e index component
        this.router.navigate(['/find']);


    }
```

On selecting city and industry the user will be routed to find page that is exactly the same and results will be displayed
[image: find.png]

**find.component.ts**

```
    export class find implements  OnInit {
  onlocationChange(event:string) {

    this.searchData[0]=event;


  }
 onIndustryChange(event:string) {
        this.searchData[1]=event;
    }

    search()
    {
       //want to call this function and getting data?        }
```

Now the main part is On my **index.html** when I click the search button how could I navigate to the **find.html** and call the function **search()** along with the data i have in My array **searchData** in **index.component**, I know one solution and that is make two different components for **finding** but I want a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Use a shared service. Store the data (here I'm using an Object) to a shared service before navigating away from your index page.

In your `find` component, retrieve the data from the shared service in the constructor. **Important** to remember is to define the service at the module level as providers, because if you declare the providers at component level, you will have two separate instances of the service, meaning the components will not have access to the same object. So let's do a demo:

Index page with two simple input fields:

```ts
<input [(ngModel)]="city" /><br>
<input [(ngModel)]="industry" /><br>
```

And in your TS, create an object and pass that object to the shared service with the values. Remember to inject the service in your constructor:

```ts
constructor(private service: Service){ }

passData() {
  this.service.emitObject({city: this.city, industry: this.industry});
  // now navigate to find component
}
```

Your service then looks like this:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class Service {

  private sharedObject = new Subject<Object>();

  sharedObject$ = this.sharedObject.asObservable();

  emitObject(obj: Object) {
    this.sharedObject.next(obj);
  }
}
```

which uses Observables. The find component then subscribes to this observable in the OnInit:

```ts
sharedObject: Object;

constructor(private service: Service) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.sharedObject$.subscribe(obj => {
     this.sharedObject = obj;
  });
}
```

And here you can use `[(ngModel)]` to bind the values in the view, in this case input fields:

```ts
<input [(ngModel)]="sharedObject.city" />
<input [(ngModel)]="sharedObject.industry" />
```

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PBChoYJWngK2dBsQdSMh?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common scenario. It should be handled as below,
Layout

```
<landing-page> 
        <search-component (applySearch)="applySearch($event)"> </search-component>
        <search-results [searchCriteria]="searchCriteria" *ngIf="searchCriteria"> </search-results>
    </landing-page>
```

LandingPageComponent.ts file

```
applySearch(SearchByValue:any){

    this.searchCriteria = SearchByValue;
}
```

In the SearchResultsComponent, the onchanges will be trigerred when ever the input properties are changed
have the searchCriteria as input property as

```
@Input() searchCriteria:Object[];

ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChange){

    //make request and get the matching data and bind to 
    this.searchedResults =  //data coming from the service resul()
}
```

In SearchComponent declare a output variable

```
@Output applySearch:EventEmitter<T> =new EventEmitter<T>();
```

button click of the event in search-component

```
 // below variable contains the two searchData
 searchData:Object=[];

this.applySearch.emit(searchData)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your requirements, you do not need to navigate to another page to show results. Just show them in index component. There are some necessary steps to take to implement it

1. Have a local variable to keep results (`jobs`). it should be empty initially
2. show `jobs` array in template using `*ngFor`
3. On search, make ajax request to get data and update `jobs`

The following is how your component may look like

```
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

    export class LandingPageComponent {
        constructor(private http: Http) {}
        jobs = [];
        industry:string;
        location:string;

        searchJobs(){
            var params = {
                industry: this.industry,
                location: this.location
            };
            this.http.get('url', {params: params})
              .toPromise()
              .then(function(result){
                       // update the array with found jobs
                       this.jobs = result.data;
                    });
        }
```

and `*ngFor` part of template:

```
// you can put country and location dropdown here
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let job of jobs">
       {{job.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

I strongly advise you to follow tutorials on [official angular website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/). It will definitely put you on the right path with angular2

Comment: but i dont want to display this info in index.html